# Can you store the position of a a multidimensional array in a variable?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a rubix cube solver and I would like to call the same edge repeatedly to check information from it. However the position of the three dimensional area takes up a lot of space, I would like to put the positions that I use repeatedly into a variable so I can call the variable instead of rewriting the position over and over.

This is what my rubix cube looks like:

```
rubixCube = [
        [["G","G","Y"], ["R","B","O"], ["R","R","O"]],
        [["G","O","O"], ["O","Y","G"], ["R","B","B"]],
        [["Y","W","Y"], ["R","O","O"], ["O","W","W"]],
        [["B","B","W"], ["B","W","G"], ["G","W","R"]],
        [["B","Y","R"], ["Y","R","W"], ["G","Y","B"]], 
        [["O","G","W"], ["B","G","R"], ["Y","Y","W"]]
        ]
```

and this is an example of a position I call repeatly:

```
if(rubixCube[0][0][1] == "W"):
```

can I write something approximately looking like this:

```
position = [0][0][1]
if(rubixCube[position] == "W"):
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about why you're trying to do this? Do you say that writing out `rubixCube[0][0][1]` is taking up to much space? Do you mean memory? Do you mean it's making your code look messy?

Answer (score 5):

if you use a numpy array

```
import numpy as np

rubixCube = np.array([
        [["G","G","Y"], ["R","B","O"], ["R","R","O"]],
        [["G","O","O"], ["O","Y","G"], ["R","B","B"]],
        [["Y","W","Y"], ["R","O","O"], ["O","W","W"]],
        [["B","B","W"], ["B","W","G"], ["G","W","R"]],
        [["B","Y","R"], ["Y","R","W"], ["G","Y","B"]],
        [["O","G","W"], ["B","G","R"], ["Y","Y","W"]]
        ])
```

then you can index it with a tuple

```
pos = (0, 0, 1)
print(rubixCude[pos])
```

Comment: And this is a short, most correct and fast working solution

Comment: @alani's answer is also a good one.  It avoids the need to pull in numpy as a dependency, and gives the same functionality.  I think it's great to have both options demonstrated here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to install `numpy`, then this would be the standard way to handle multidimensional arrays.

If you want to keep within the standard library in order to avoid the need to install additional packages, you could make an indexer class to sit on top of your existing nested list, which will allow you to get and set elements using a tuple (or list) for the position.

```
class NdIndexer:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        val = self.arr
        for i in index:
            val = val[i]
        return val

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        val = self.arr
        for i in index[:-1]:
            val = val[i]
        val[index[-1]] = value
```

You can then do:

```
rubixCube = [
    [["G","G","Y"], ["R","B","O"], ["R","R","O"]],
    [["G","O","O"], ["O","Y","G"], ["R","B","B"]],
    [["Y","W","Y"], ["R","O","O"], ["O","W","W"]],
    [["B","B","W"], ["B","W","G"], ["G","W","R"]],
    [["B","Y","R"], ["Y","R","W"], ["G","Y","B"]], 
    [["O","G","W"], ["B","G","R"], ["Y","Y","W"]]
]

cube = NdIndexer(rubixCube)
position = (0,0,1)

# getting
print(rubixCube[0][0][1])  # prints: G
print(cube[position])  # prints: G

# setting
cube[position] = "X"

print(rubixCube[0][0][1])  # prints: X
print(cube[position])  # prints: X
```

Comment: This is a nice answer. I would prefer this answer if I didn't need any other functionality from `numpy`.  (Sorry for my earlier (stupid) comment.)

Comment: @Steve Didn't see the comment, but whatever it was, no worries.

Comment: I had said that your answer was a dup of the first, which it is obviously exactly not.